# Using URI with HTTPS

Tags: https, uwp, uri

I wrote a program on UWP that stores text in a .txt file which is then voiced to the client. This worked really well when using an HTTP URI but now that site uses HTTPS the program crashes with the error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().'
```

The line that it crashes on is:

```
Byte[] bytes = await cli.GetByteArrayAsync(uriBing);
```

If I change the link to HTTP the program works fine again. Does anyone know how I can fix this please? Or is it just not possible?

```
var uriBing = new Uri(@"https://mydomain/net/hal2001/Actions/HALSpeak/speak.txt");

//set storageFolder as the location of the local app storage folder.
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

//Create a local file to be used to write the URL file to.
StorageFile sampleFile2 = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("status2.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

//Write to local file the value stored in the URL file so they match.
var cli = new HttpClient();

Byte[] bytes = await cli.GetByteArrayAsync(uriBing);
```

If Have tried the following but still not happy.

```
   HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
            HttpClient cli = new HttpClient(handler);
```

I checked the IIS server application > SSL Settings and SSL Settings is set to 'Require SSL' with client certificates set to Accept.

Comment: Try to add `client.TransportSettings.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I have tested with your code, it works well with https request, please make sure your web server supported https protocol.

Comment: @maximdj: Have you tried hitting the HTTPS URI with a tool like Postman?

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this and post answer if I am able to get it working.

Comment: @maximdj, Does it work now, any updates about this issue ?

Comment: not yet, I have not had chance to test. Will test tomorrow.

Comment: I tried to add: client.TransportSettings.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd"); but client is not recognized. If I type the URI in the browser I can view the text file on the computer that the UWP app is running.

Comment: I don't think the issue occur in uwp client. you need check your server. you could also test with browser